# Climbing Movement (stay in place)

Tags: movement, actions, pathfinder-2e, falling

A creature making use of climbing movement, on a suitable surface, when interrupting its movement during climbing, can it act freely by remaining in the place where it is? Is it necessary to spend an action and/or occupy one or both hands while remaining motionless? Is there any risk of falling while immobile, if targeted by something/effect, even if the creature has climbing movement?

Comment: FWIW, if you're planning on doing a lot of climbing in combat, you might be interested in [Combat Climber](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=768).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Requirements** You have both hands free.
>
> You move up, down, or across an incline.

The [Climb](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=33) action is only attempted when moving. No action is required to stay stationary on a surface, and the requirements here taking up both hands would only apply while taking the action (though letting go completely could cause a fall depending on the circumstance).

> If you would be knocked prone while you're Climbing or Flying, you fall

Most effects don't cause a creature clinging to a surface to fall unless it moves them out of reach of the surface or knocks them [prone](https://2e.aonprd.com/Conditions.aspx?ID=31). Using a reaction to [Grab an Edge](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=95) at the same DC as the Climb is a good way for those creatures to stop falling in those cases.